# aws bottlerocketOS container runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, operating-system, container-runtime-interface

I'm trying to test docker container runtime on a aws bottlerocketOS instance. The instance is created on ec2. Instance userdata has docker service enabled as mentioned [here](https://github.com/bottlerocket-os/bottlerocket/blob/develop/sources/models/src/aws-dev/override-defaults.toml). After enabling host-container.admin and ssh into the server, docker seem to not exist. Also as per docs there is support for [docker service](https://github.com/bottlerocket-os/bottlerocket/blob/develop/packages/docker-engine/docker.service). I guess i'm missing something, really appreciate your time in here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not exist'? Where have you looked and what were you looking for? Is the service running (`systemctl status docker`)?

Comment: bottle rocket comes with containerd, not docker.  The output of the above docker status command is `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`. As a root user i get:`Running in chroot, ignoring request`

Comment: Have you tried executing `sheltie` to get out of admin container to actual host?

Comment: yeah, it says `failed to start docker.service`

Comment: the problem is I have manually added docker to the host and trying to bring it up. complains about unit file docker.service does not exist.